# Create alias of part of a list in python

Tags: python, list, pointer-aliasing

Is there a way to get an alias for a part of a list in python?

Specifically, I want the equivalent of this to happen:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a=l
>>> l[0]=10
>>> a
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But what I get is this:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a=l[0:2]
>>> l[0]=10
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Slicing creates a new `list`. If you had two `list`s of different sizes, how could they be the same list, i.e., have the same address?

Comment: I guess you could embed each element into its own `list`, but that would be so hacky. You probably have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If numpy is an option:

```
import  numpy as np

l = np.array(l)

a = l[:2]

l[0] = 10

print(l)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[10  2  3  4  5]
[10  2]
```

slicing with basic indexing returns a view  object with numpy so any change are reflected in the [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) object

Or use a [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) with an [array.array:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array)

```
from array import array

l = memoryview(array("l", [1, 2, 3, 4,5]))

a = l[:2]

l[0]= 10
print(l.tolist())

print(a.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[10, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could embed each element into its own mutable data structure (like a `list`).

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l = [[item] for item in l]
>>> l
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> a = l[:2]
>>> a
[[1], [2]]
>>> l[0][0] = 10
>>> l
[[10], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> a
[[10], [2]]
```

However, I recommend trying to come up with a solution to your original issue (whatever that was) that doesn't create issues of its own.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a view of the original list, so that any modifications are reflected in the original list. This is doable with the array in the numpy package:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y = x[2:]
>>> y[0] = 999
>>> x
array([  1,   2, 999])
```